# Make private sub run when formula changes

Tags: excel, vba

I've searched for an answer to this but can't find it. I have the following code to dynamically name a button:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5")) Is Nothing Then _
Me.Buttons(1).Caption = Range("E5").Value
End Sub
```

Where "E5" is linked "D5", which in turn is linked to "A5" - i.e. "E5" updates when "A5" changes, via "D5".

How do I change this code so the sub will run when A5 is changed by the user? I'm going to eventually have multiple buttons on this page that need dynamic names, so the best change would be one that runs all private subs when any change is made on the sheet...if that's possible!

Thanks so much all help - really appreciate it!

DDT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' if the cell being changed is A5
    If Target.Address = Me.Range("$A$5").Address Then
        ' if E5 is not blank
        If Me.Range("$E$5").Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            ' change the buttons Name
            Me.Buttons(1).Name = Me.Range("$E$5").Value2
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Your `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5")) Is Nothing Then` is getting the intersection of your changed range and `Range("E5")`. Since `Range("A5")` never intersects with `Range("E5")`, your code will always return `Nothing` and thus always fail.

Note that this changes the buttons *name* but not the text that is displayed on the button. If you want the button to display different text, you can simply select your button and, in the formula bar, set its formula to `=$E$5`.

Comment: Thanks @TheFizh - perfect answer.